# How to Dispose() a specific User control from panel control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dispose

I want to dispose a specific type of User control from panel. Right now i am using foreach loop to dispose the User control.

```
foreach (CTRL.box bx in RightPanel.Controls.OfType<CTRL.box>())
{
     bx.Dispose();
}
```

But it is not working properly. while checking in google i find the below code.

```
while(tabControlToClear.Controls.Count > 0)
{ 
var tabPage = tabControlToClear.Controls[0];
tabControlToClear.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
tabPage.Dispose(); 

// Clear out events.

foreach (EventHandler subscriber in tabPage.Click.GetInvocationList())
{
    tabPage.Click -= subscriber;
}
}
```

I am trying to do this, But for me it is a specific User control i need to dispose. they are other User controls which should be required in my form. Overall i want to dispose **box** User control from my form.

```
while (RightPanel.Controls.OfType<CTRL.box>().Count() > 0)
{
      var panel = RightPanel.Controls.OfType<CTRL.box>()[0];//Here i am getting error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project_Server.CTRL.box>'"
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` interface does not specify an indexer property. Are there more than one `CTRL.box` controls? If so, can you identify them at runtime by some property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is pretty clear, you cannot apply indexing on `IEnumerable`

I would suggest use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` extension method to retrieve first element and delete it.

```
var panel = RightPanel.Controls.OfType<CTRL.box>().FirstOrDefault();
if(panel != null) 
{
    //logic
}
```

In case, if you would like to remove all controls of type `CTRL.box` use this.

```
List<Control> controls= RightPanel.Controls.OfType<CTRL.box>().ToList();

foreach(Control c in controls)
{
    RightPanel.Controls.Remove(c);
    c.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: That's true, we could do that.

Comment: If you're retrieving `FirstOrDefault()` what's the point of that `while` loop?

Comment: @CoolBots That's valid point, not really sure op wants to delete all the controls or just one control. Let me update it for both the scenarios.

Comment: Thanks @HariPrasad, i want to remove all the controls of that type. It's working fine.